# Inlin JS not working with Flask and Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-5

I am building a Flask web app with Bootstrap 5 and trying to inline a JS but it is not working

I am trying to use a simple `alert()` component but nothing is showing.

If i write the same code in my console on Chrome, it works.

My code is as such:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/favicon.png') }}">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    

    <title>
        {% block title %}

        {% endblock %}
    </title>

  </head>
  <body>
            
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
      <symbol id="check-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z"/>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="info-fill" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 16A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm.93-9.412-1 4.705c-.07.34.029.533.304.533.194 0 .487-.07.686-.246l-.088.416c-.287.346-.92.598-1.465.598-.703 0-1.002-.422-.808-1.319l.738-3.468c.064-.293.006-.399-.287-.47l-.451-.081.082-.381 2.29-.287zM8 5.5a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"/>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="exclamation-triangle-fill" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5c.535 0 .954.462.9.995l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 5.995A.905.905 0 0 1 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
      </symbol>
    </svg>

    {% block body %}

    {% endblock %}

    <script language="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('TEST')
       alert("Hello world - Alert");
     });
     </script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    
    

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

  </body>
</html>
```

When i load the page, nothing appears. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

The `language` attribute of the `script` element was [never standardized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-language), don't use it. Replace it with `type` or you can even omit it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('TEST')
    alert("Hello world - Alert")
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case, still not sure of the cause.

Earlier, I had the javascript code outside the blocks.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
   ...
   ...
{% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form-submit-btn").click( function(e){
    ...
    ...
</script>
```

After moving the javascript code inside the blocks, it started working.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
   ...
   ...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form-submit-btn").click( function(e){
    ...
    ...
</script>
{% endblock %}
```